# At sixes and sevens

Tags: idioms

If things are in a mess, they're all "at sixes and sevens." Now, who says this in Britain? Would a working-class person say at sixes and sevens?

Comment: The phrase is “at sixes and sevens.” See this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A%20sixes%20and%20sevens&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binto%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2C

Comment: Just an opinion of course but I think it's a bit archaic these days.  An older person would be more likely to say it, and I don't think there's much of a class specificity.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I think you're right, in fact I think it's been going out of widespread use for the last sixty to seventy years.

Comment: So what would a, e.g., a Yorkshire or Cumbrian farmer say instead of sixes and sevens?

Answer (score 1):

[These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+sixes+and+sevens%2Cin+a+mess%2Cin+disarray%2Call+over+the+place&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20sixes%20and%20sevens%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20mess%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20disarray%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20over%20the%20place%3B%2Cc0) would seem to show that the use of the idiom (from both unusual word-sense and unusual grammar perspectives) is not in decline, though other equivalent expressions have become far more natural. (Though there will be false positives for 'all over the place' especially.)

[image]

As to distribution, I'd say that the examples in the sporting pages of the press, for instance:

- *Did Aston Villa and Tottenham play well or were Liverpool and Manchester United at sixes and sevens?*

[[Premier Skills English_British Council; Oct 2020](https://premierskillsenglish.britishcouncil.org/skills/listen/week/week-sixes-and-sevens)] (an example showing excellent wordplay)

keep the expression alive among all social classes.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that it is rather unlikely to hear the expression "at sixes and sevens" said by, for example, workers on a factory floor or those performing manual work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).